# Global hardware OnKeyPress

Tags: c#, api, keyboard, keylogger

I have in C# this function , for key press. When you press a key will be executed function a()

> protected virtual void
>   OnKeyPress(object sender,
>   KeyPressEventArgs e)
>   {
>   a();
>   }

I need a method which to execute a function globally, in outside of my application , in outside of .NET Framework , anywhere in Windows.

Advanced thanks you!

PS: I don`t want to develop a malicious application,  a constructive (antikeylogger method) ;)

Comment: I'm absolutely positive this is a duplicate (sorry) . . . but I can't find the original. Some one was asking how to write a key logger, this ringing any bells for anyone?

Answer (score 2):

This article at CodeProject describes how you can install a Global Keyboard hook using .Net/C# to get that event you need.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx